# welfare economics journals

Tags: microeconomics, welfare-economics

Does anyone know of journals related to welfare economics?
If not, what is the next best alternative to find articles (preferably open access) related to current research in welfare economics?

Thanks

Comment: There is a journal names "Social Choice and Welfare" that focuses on welfare economics. Also, I would expect that many journals on Public Economics would have a large amount of papers related to welfare and social choice

Comment: Journal of public economics may be the better option for applied welfare economics. Social choice and welfare may be the better option for the theory of welfare economics.

Answer (score 3):

This is from the end of the first chapter in the book *Public Finance in Canada 4th edition* by Harvy Rosen.

This book is  a primer for welfare economics. The book states gives a list of:

- Journal of Public Economics
- Canadian Tax Journal
- National Tax Journal
- Public Finance
- Public Finance Quarterly
- International Tax and Public Finance
- Journal of Public Economic Theory
- Economics of Governance

Also remember most general interest economic journals also publish articles that deal with welfare economics/public finance issues.

Hope this list helps